# Find dictionary matches from list of base class

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, casting

I have a quite odd question. I am working on a big project and i am implementing a core feature after millions of lines of code. I am not allowed to alter some parts of the code and it seems like i have to try this way.

I have two classes as `A` and `B`. A is derived from B.

```
public class B{}
public class A : B{}
```

I have a `SortedList<string, A>`, i need to cast the `SortedList` into `List<B>`. Operate on `List<B>` then cast the list into `SortedList` again.

For example:

```
SortedList<string, B> items;
public List<A> GetItems()
{
   return items.Values.Cast<B>().ToList(); //Getting values works
}

public void SetItems(List<B> newItems)
{
    items = CastWithMagic(newItems); //How to make casting work?
}
```

There are 2 possible changes on `A` items.

- Changes on `B`(base class variables)
- Removed items from the list.

I want to apply changes on `List<B>` to `SortedList<string, A>`

Comment: It seems like you lost the sort key when you transform into a `List<B>`.  Is the sort key some property of `B` that you can get back? Also note that any change you make to the `B` objects in the list get applied to the `B` objects in the sorted list since both lists contain _references_ to the `B` objects.

Comment: Do you strictly need to return List<A>, or could you return `IList<T>` instead?

Comment: List<T> would make harder to adapt the new system for other developers so i am trying to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are 2 possible changes on A items.
>
> - Changes on B(base class variables)
> - Removed items from the list.

Changes to the objects will be reflected in both lists, since the lists just contain *references* to the same objects.  So all you should need to handle is objects that are deleted from the `List`. I believe you'll have to loop through the sorted list to see if the objects have been removed from the list:

```
public void SetItems(List<B> newItems)
{
    foreach(string key in items.Keys)
    {
        if(!newItems.Contains(items[key] as B))
            items.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Note that this is inefficient since you're looping through both collections, making it `O(m*n)` - if your collections are small and performance is not critical then you may be OK, but start with this and find ways to make it more efficient (maybe removing from the source collection instead of the copied list?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will check if the changes are reflected. If object reference is lost somewhere in items.Values.Cast<B>().ToList(); then it is fine for me too. I can reflect changes by myself.

Comment: Extra comment: i created a variable named index in base class so i don't have to loop through one list

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use Linq's 'select' function for this.  Take this example code:

```
private void test()
{
    List<alphaClass> firstList = new List<alphaClass>();
    List<betaClass> secondList = firstList.Select(z => (betaClass)z).ToList();
}

public class alphaClass { }
public class betaClass : alphaClass { }
```

(This assumes everything from the list can be cast as the derived class.)

Anyway, linq's SELECT statement can be used to transform an `IEnumerable` into a different form. In this case, transforming it from one class to another.

---

EDIT: Whoops - missed the Sorted List part.  That can be taken care of by using an extension method I found for a different question:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<TSource, TKey, TValue>
(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
 Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector)
    {
        var ret = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            ret.Add(keySelector(element), valueSelector(element));
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

... and then, from here, you can use that extension like this:

```
SortedList<string, betaClass> myList = new SortedList<string, betaClass>();
SortedList<string, alphaClass> secondList;
secondList = myList.ToSortedList(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (alphaClass) kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will try your method, but i suppose i need to store keys somewhere in B

Comment: `Cast<T>()` does effectively the same thing as `Select(o => (T)o)`